# How to add Custom Tag in QuickFix/J

Tags: quickfixj

I am trying to add OrderRestrictions 529 in Fix5.0 dictionary. How to do it without building the library? I also wondering if there is any config that allow me handling unsupported/unrecognized Tag manually from client side?

I tried adding these configs

```
AllowUnknownMsgFields=Y
ValidateUserDefinedFields=N
ValidateIncomingMessage=N
```

No luck yet

Comment: What is the exact error that you get? Which QFJ version are you using? Do you only want to receive messages with this field? BTW, tag 529 was added in FIX4.3, and it is available in a default FIX5.0 dictionary.

Comment: @ChristophJohn here is the message
`8=FIXT.1.19=10935=j34=449=BEX50=XXXXX52=20240115-06:02:15.58256=XXX45=358=Unsupported Message Type372=8380=310=238`

Comment: You answered only part of my questions. However, that message tells you that a certain message type is not supported.

Comment: @ChristophJohn Sorry for replying late. Counter party was sending message in FIX5.0sp1. Your comment ensured about Tag 529 and helped me thinking it in another angle. Thanks